# laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to start laravel,

Found the following line in their tutorial:

> Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH
>   so the laravel executable is found when you run the laravel command in
>   your terminal.

I don't understand what I should do ?

I added `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to my system variables,  and then tried using 'laravel new blog' in the command line  but got the following message :

`laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command`

what should I do?

Comment: Did you first run "composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1" "?

Comment: What OS are you running and trying to do this?

Comment: Yes I ran composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1 at first
and I'm using windows 8.1 operating system

Comment: @darroosh I hope your problem got resolved when you used the absolute path instead of the relative one. Please accept Mantas D's answer and close this question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For Windows add

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

... to directory by going to "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment > Variables" > "Path".

Note: MyUserName is your pc username .

Restart your PC and it would work

Comment: Upvoted. Took me 2 restarts and some insane copy pasting the same text over and over after the first restart to make it work.

Can't believe we had to go through some acrobatics just for this. Don't know if it's just bad docu or that the way people treat devs on windows OS is just discriminating.

Comment: @jagc 1 for the windows discriminating part, I love linux, but sometimes you just need the "bad" windows

Comment: I didn't restart my pc. just tried opening new cmd.

Comment: on Windows 10 it didn't work when I just opened new cmd, after restarting it works

Answer (score 54):

Use correct path to the Composer `bin` directory.

Good:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

Bad:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your console and open again

Comment: Note: if you already have Path variables you can add more by seperating them with ; took me a while to find out, might help somebody

Comment: On windows you must use an absolute path

Comment: If you are adding this to your path using My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment > Variables" > "Path" you should use the Path in the top box called "User variables for <username>" and not the Path in System variables. When using the System variables Path %USERPROFILE% will not be set correctly.  Note, in addition, I also needed to add @php C:\php\composer.phar %* in a file at c:\php\composer.bat for "laravel new blog" to work properly.

Answer (score 22):

For me after adding PATH to environment variables result was the same. I found me answer [*here*](https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/07-05-2015-cant-get-the-laravel-command-to-run-in-the-cmd)

So at first you have to run in cmd

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

and then the message appears

> " Changing directory to
>   C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin "

and after that you can run your command. For example

```
laravel new blog
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to install Laravel using

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Otherwise, even adding it to PATH won't help.

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

First, use:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Then, you can try again.

```
laravel new project
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happening few many reasons like wrong installation path and conflicts with previous project creation. To solve this problem
first:   composer global require laravel/installer
then: laravel new admin ProjectName

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was writing larabel when it's laravel.
I say this because maybe the same thing happens to someone.

Answer (score -2):

this command has solved my problem.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Comment: what problem ?  Add explanation please