# Laravel installation withouth vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php

Is it possible to install Laravel Framework withouth installing vagrant first?

I just read about vagrant and seems just great, however I think I will skip it for now.

I "installed" Laravel through composer, but when I tried to use the Laravel command:

`new <app-name>`

The console outputs:

`laravel command not found.`

I already set the **~/.composer/vendor/bin** route to the `$PATH`

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528583/laravel-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Sounds like your trying to install it via the the laravel installer, rather than composer.

Comment: have you installed composer ? have you installed laravel ?

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.profile` file you should have something like this if you are using a mac

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:${PATH}"
```

If you are using Ubuntu you should have something like this in your `~/.profile` file

```
PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Finally, if you haven't installed the CLI tool for the Laravel Installer just run this code in the terminal

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I executed that line before but it wasn't working. I just restarted my machine and for some reason that script is already working. BTW, that doesn't entirely answer my question, so from now on, I can still use laravel withouth installing vagrant?

Comment: you can use laravel without installing vagrant

Comment: To use Laravel without vagrant you would need to install the full LEMP or LAMP stack in your computer, but yeah, it is possible, just install the stack the same way you would do it on your production server but in your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install laravel in order to use it.

Use `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` to install laravel